# How to get child injectors(services) list from a component in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

I have a component called Parent component and there is child component1 and child component2. Both child components extends parent component.
I injected service A and service B to child component1
I injected service C and service D to child component2.
these child components are lazy loaded components.

Now, I need those services from parent component on request.
How to get services list from parent component whatever is injected under that hierarchy, I should get all the services under that child component injectors.

Please let me know a way to get those services.

Comment: Where do you want to access the service list?

Comment: In the another component, basically to show the current changes on the view from those services.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you can add services on `this`, since the parent and child
>   share same `this` object you can access child services in the parent.

```
class Parent {
    someMethod() {
       this.serviceList // there you will get all the dependencies of the Child.
   }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    serviceList: Array<any> = []
    constructor(inj Injector) {
           this.serviceList.push ( inj.get(<Dependency1>) );
           this.serviceList.push ( inj.get(<Dependency2>) );
     }
}
```